# wp-mail attachment is not sent for no reason?

Tags: plugins, php, directory, wp-mail

I'm using wp-mail to send an image. The problem is that it does not attach the image !

Here is `$attachment_img` string : `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/example.jpg` So the path is correct

Here is the function :

```
function send_mail_to_admin($orderId , $attachment_img){
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: انجمن آبزیان <info@seabou.com>');
    $body = "<html><body>
    <b style='font-size:14px;direction:rtl;text-align:center;'>یک مشتری سفارش با شماره $orderId ثبت کرد</b>
    </body></html>"; 
    wp_mail( "nabestan98@gmail.com", "دریافت نامه کاربر", $body, $headers , array($attachment_img) );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code to this and it worked ! Don't know why I should do this and this is very odd but whatever.

```
function send_mail_to_admin($orderId , $attachment_img){
    $attachment_img = str_replace("https://seabou.com/wp-content" , "" , $attachment_img);
    $attachment_img = array(  WP_CONTENT_DIR . $attachment_img );
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: انجمن آبزیان <info@seabou.com>');
    $body = "<html><body>
    <b style='font-size:14px;direction:rtl;text-align:center;'>یک مشتری سفارش با شماره $orderId ثبت کرد</b>
    </body></html>"; 
    wp_mail( "nabestan98@gmail.com", "دریافت نامه کاربر", $body, $headers , $attachment_img );
}
```

Comment: It's because the wp_mail $attachments argument takes file paths not URLs. Can you construct the attachment_img as a path not an URL? I don't know how you're getting the URL but if you're constructing it from WordPress functions there are usually equivalent functions to get the path instead.